# What eloquent relation should I use in my multiple model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, relation

I am working with viewing a certain orders base from orders id. I have no problem displaying the company connected to the orders but later I realize i need also to **display the contact person from that company who ordered** I need to display that in view.

Upon digging I learned that i could use **hasManyThrough** but don't know how to actually display the data. I am not even sure if **hasManyThrough** can give what I need.

Here's the simplified table relation;

```
Companies                Contacts                 Orders
   id                  companies_id             company_id
```

**contacts table screen**

[image]

**Companies table**

[image]

**orders table**

[image]

**Companies Model**

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Orders::class, 
        Contacts::class, 
        'companies_id', 
        'company_id', 
        'id', 
        'id' 
    );
}
```

**Orders Model**

```
public function companies()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\Companies', 'id','company_id');
}

public function contact()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\Contacts', 'id','companies_id');
}
```

I am trying to display the data like this

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <strong>TO:</strong>
    <h4>{{ $orders->companies->comp_name }}</h4> //this is ok
    <p>{{ $orders->companies->comp_address }}</p> //this is ok
    <p>{{ $orders->contact['cont_name'] }}</p> //this should be the contact person from that company
</div>
```

any suggestion on how can I achieve this? thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Please descript tell me all tables structure

Comment: Hi @AvinashRathod I just updated my question. thanks!

Comment: Hve you tried $orders->contact->cont_name ?

Comment: yes but it throws an error 'Trying to get property of non-object ' that's why end up doing this '$orders->contact['cont_name']'

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, In your model company, you need to have a function for hasMany orders and hasMany contacts. In your contacts and your orders model, a function for belongsTo company.

Comment: In your design your want a Company to have only 1 Contact person or Many? So you would need to retrieve that one Contact?

Comment: company can have multiple contact person. and will only retrieve the last contact person. So the scenario is when I open an ORDER, the company that is assigned to that specific order should display its details together with the last contact person in that company.

Comment: Thanks @LitoLozada I hope you have got the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `hasManyThrough` on a Cascade 1-to-Many-to-Many style. Like an Artist has Many Albums that has Many Songs, so an Artist has Many Songs through Albums (Artist->Albums->Songs).

In your case :

1- Company has One or multiple Contacts, let's say you will limit it to 1 with your Business Logic codes

2- A Company has Many Orders and an Order belongs To a Company

3- A Contact belongs to a Company

So you can use the Codes :

**UPDATE** -----

As you specify in Comment that Company can have Multiple Contacts, then you can define an additional `hasMany` relation to Contact.

---

In Companies Model

```
<?php
// Companies model

public function contact()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\Contacts', 'companies_id');
}

public function contacts()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Contacts', 'companies_id');
}

public function orders()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Orders', 'company_id');
}
```

In Contact Model

```
<?php
// Contacts model
// Keep it singular since it's only one Company
public function company()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Companies', 'companies_id');
}
```

In Order Model

```
<?php
// Orders model
// Keep it singular since it's only one Company
public function company()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Companies', 'company_id');
}
```

And finally in the Blade view

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <strong>TO:</strong>
    <h4>{{ $orders->company->comp_name }}</h4> //this is ok
    <p>{{ $orders->company->comp_address }}</p> //this is ok
    <p>{{ $orders->company->contact->cont_name }}</p> //this should be ok
</div>
```

Comment: This is amazing!!! It works! I will really really take note of this @KeitelDOG I appreciate this very much.