# Order Items can't display in purchase order view in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hi need your help please. I can't make the order items display in order view. I am using the belongsToMany relation.

**Order Model**

```
public function orderitems()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Orderitems', 'id', 'order_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    // return $this->belongsToMany(Orderitems::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}
```

**orderitems model**

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Orders', 'id','order_id');
}
```

**Show Blade**

```
@foreach($orders->orderitems as $orderitem)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $orderitem->product_code }}</td>
    <td>{{ $orderitem->product_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $orderitem->quantity }}</td>
    <td>{{ $orderitem->total_cost }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

**OrdersController**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $orders = Orders::find($id);
    return view('orders.show')->with('orders', $orders);
}
```

hope you can help me. thank you so much in advance!

**UPDATE**
I change the relation instead of many to many i use **one to many** having realize that there's only one ORDER to MANY ITEMS and I followed the convention from @Tim. here's now what my models and controller's look like

**orders model**

```
public function orderItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Orderitems', 'id', 'order_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}
```

**orderitems model**

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Orders','id','order_id');
}
```

**controller**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $order = Orders::find($id);
    $orderItems = $order->orderItems; 
    dd($order->orderitems);
    Log::info($order);
    var_dump($order);        
}
```

the result of dd is empty
[image]

Comment: So many convention issues... Model names are singular, `Order`, not `Orders`, variable name should be `$order` since `::find()` returns a single order, not multiple, relations are usually camelCase `orderItems()` or snake_case `order_items()`, etc. That all being said, try to run a `dd($orders->orderitems)` in your controller to see if there are actually order items attached.

Comment: I suspect two main possible issues here:
1) `belongsToMany` is not the correct relationship type for the hierarchy you're aiming to achieve;
2) `order_id` is set as your first foreign key from both sides of the eventual `belongsToMany`, leading to a contradiction
Both would result in an empty array being returned. Check out your database relation structure again.

Comment: Hi @TimLewis i just applied your suggestion. it gave me this error,--- SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'brandexpertpos.id' doesn't exist (SQL: select `order_items`.*, `id`.`order_id` as `pivot_order_id`, `id`.`orderitems_id` as `pivot_orderitems_id` from `order_items` inner join `id` on `order_items`.`id` = `id`.`orderitems_id` where `id`.`order_id` = 2 order by `created_at` desc) (View: E:\wamp64\www\brandExpertPOS\resources\views\orders\show.blade.php)

Comment: hi @D.Petrov what can you suggest?

Comment: Need multiple rows change this `Orders::find($id);` to this `Orders::where('id',$id)->get();` and can you please check in your blade what is the output of this `$orders->orderitems` ?

Comment: Hi @ViperTecPro i just followed your suggestion. i think it broke other connected model. --- Property [companies] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: yes i was wrong sorry my bad , umm don't you think in inverse relation orderitems this should switch `'id','order_id'` ?  and i think Tim Lewis is right about convention issues ...

Comment: it is working now! i just switch the position of id and order_id in orders model. to look like this.         return $this->hasMany('App\Orderitems', 'order_id', 'id')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');

Comment: @D.Petrov you suspected it right. belongsToMany is not correct relation.

Comment: @TimLewis thanks your comments helps a lot!

Comment: and @ViperTecPro thanks also! cheers guys!

Answer (score 1):

When using many-to-many `belongsToMany`, in Order model you need

1- Orderitems Class

2- many-to-many table name

3- Order ID (Parent)

4- Orderitems ID (Children in this many case)

But as you've switched to 1-to-many `hasMany` you need only the Foreign Key. Use in Orders model :

```
<?php
// in Orders model
public function orderItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Orderitems', 'order_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}
```

And in Orderitems model :

```
<?php
// in Orderitems model
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Orders', 'order_id');
}
```

Comment: i'll take note of this @keitelDOG. Thanks. BTW i have another question you might help me with, here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54943359/what-eloquent-relation-should-i-use-in-my-multiple-model-in-laravel .

Comment: Ok I will look at it